# how to i get only .txt formate file list from folder using php, codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

*I want to only .txt format files are display but all files are
 displaying on screen*

**controller code is**

```
$this->load->helper('directory');  
$data['files'] = directory_map('./software_files');
```

**and view side code is**

```
if(isset($files) && count($files) > 0 ){  
    foreach($files as $file){  
        echo $file."<br/>";  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Just check the file extension before echoing the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You can use pathinfo() with `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` to check the extension for file :*

```
foreach ($files as $file) 
{

    if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'txt')
    {
        //echo $file;
        $data[] = $file;
    }
}

print_r($data);
/*list all .txt file*/
```

for more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to find filenames matching a pattern. Add `*.txt` in path to get specific type files list from directory.

```
$files = array();
foreach( glob("./software_files/*.txt") as $file )
{
    echo $file."<br/>";
}
```

## UPDATE

If you want to print filename only even without file extension, Use the following line

```
echo basename($file,".txt")."<br/>";
```

Instead of

```
echo $file."<br/>";
```

Comment: all paths are print like this                                    ./software_files/Event.txt
 ./software_files/Language.txt
 ./software_files/Links.txt

Comment: What is your desire output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$directory = "mytheme/images/myimages";
$images = glob($directory . "*.txt");

foreach($images as $image)
{
  echo $image;
}
```